# Getting and matching values from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which is like this:

```
var Data=[{
    "Class":"item1","element":["a","b","c","d","e"],
    "Class":"item2","element":["a","b","c","d","e"],
    "Class":"item3","element":["a","b","c","d","e"],
    "Class":"item4","element":["a","b","c","d","e"]
}];
```

I have two variables:

```
var class='item1';
var element='a';
```

I want a condition that if var class values match "item1" then var element value should be matched with its elements only like:

if (class == Data.Class) then element should be matched with Data.element near it

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `Data` variable is wrong. How can you have same key/value pairs 4 times. Only the last one will be stored.

Comment: The object in your `Data` array redefines `"Class"` and `"element"`. Did you mean for each line to be a separate object in the array?

Comment: yes freejosh and what should be best structure for it mohkhan

Comment: It should be like this 

var Data=[
    { "Class":"item1", "element":["a","b","c","d","e"] },
    { "Class":"item2", "element":["a","b","c","d","e"] },
    { "Class":"item3", "element":["a","b","c","d","e"] },
    { "Class":"item4", "element":["a","b","c","d","e"] }
}];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be your data...

```
var Data= [
    { "Class":"item1","element":["a","b","c","d","e"] },
    { "Class":"item2","element":["a","b","c","d","e"] },
    { "Class":"item3","element":["a","b","c","d","e"] },
    { "Class":"item4","element":["a","b","c","d","e"] },
];
```

Then you can iterate over it and find your value. Like this

```
var class='item1';
var element='a';
for(var i = 0; i < Data.length; ++i){
    if (Data[i].Class == class){
        for( var j = 0; j < Data[i].element.length; ++j){
            if ( Data[i].elements[j] == element){
               // do whatever
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check and tell me what is wrong with this its not accepting the data for same element http://jsfiddle.net/StaHg/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to fix your `data`

```
var Data= [
    { "Class":"item1","element":["a","b","c","d","e"] },
    { "Class":"item2","element":["a","b","c","d","e"] },
    { "Class":"item3","element":["a","b","c","d","e"] },
    { "Class":"item4","element":["a","b","c","d","e"] },
];
```

Now it is an array of objects.

Then you can look into that array, for example with a `for` loop

```
var myclass = "item3"; // class is a reserved word
for (var i=0; i<Data.length;i++) {
    if (Data[i].Class == myclass) {
        // do something with that its data Data[i].element
    }
}
```

Comment: well whatever you want to do now.. thats up to you. You didn't specify what you want with that.